# How to override resource (.resx) behaviour

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

We are applying localization in our application by using resx files and using it by calling Resources.Resource.Key and ResourceManager class to get the values of keys. Currently we are facing an issue that in some languages single (') and double quotes (") are appearing while in English resource there is no such thing like that. Problem is that when we calls javascript methods like alert('value') in code then it crashes because single quote within another single quote does not work. I know there is way to handle it by replacing single quote with "\'" but in order to fix this I need to write this code throughout the application. Is there any workaround that whenever I call the resource by calling above ways I mentioned earlier One method automatically called in which I can modify the value return by the resource. Waiting for your valuable suggestions. Thx

Comment: waiting for your response. Still stuck is issue. plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere you're referencing resources you should HTML encode the output. If you're using ASP.NET WebForms you can use `<%: Resources.Strings.Something %>`. If you're using the Razor view engine then it will be HTML encoded by default.